# Customize Laravel validation lang file path

Tags: laravel, validation

I want to customize default validation lang file paht from `project/resources/lang/en/validation.php` to `project/resources/lang/admin/en/validation.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add new `DomainApplication.php` in `app` folder

```
<?php namespace App;

class DomainApplication extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Application {
    public function langPath() {
        return '/path/to/new/lang/';
    }
}
```

Then in `/bootstrap/start.php` replace `$app` with

```
$app = new App\DomainApplication(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);
```

[Source](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-lang-from-another-path?page=1&replyId=34855)

Comment: but okay https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-lang-from-another-path?page=1&replyId=34855